# working with textfields in net beans

Tags: java

I know how to get the data from my textfield and display it to my textarea, but I want to know how i can keep appending data to my textarea each time it is typed into my textfield and the jbutton is pushed. I am using netbeans 6.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an append(String str) function on the JTextArea class that probably does what you need.

So you probably need something like:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jTextArea1.append(jTextField1.getText());
}
```

Edited based on comment below since I had meant to say it was JTextArea#append() and I added an example action performed method.

Comment: it also exists on JTextArea (which is the field needing it in this case).